# Send file from the wso2 emm server to the devices or launch application

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

i would like to know if it's possible to send a file, such as pdf or txt or others, from the MDM WSO2 server to a device controlled. Otherwise if it's possible to launch an application from the server to the client..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both features are is not available in WSO2 EMM at the moment.

Comment: OH.. it's a shame.. it's a good tool but there are no some important features.. I hope in the future will be implemented..